# Given a non-negative integer y, you are write a program to find the largest non-negative integer x such that x^2 + x ≤ y

Tags: python

Given a non-negative integer y, you are write a program to find the largest non-negative integer x such that
x^2 + x ≤ y

You may assume that the given value of y is an integer in the range 0 ... 10**17 (inclusive).

*** You may not use the math module or the power operator (x ** y) or the round function in your code.

**Input Specification**

An integer y in the range 0 ... 10^17 (inclusive)

**Output Specification**

The non-negative value of x

Example:
Input:
100000000000000000
Output: 316227765

My code is something like this:

```
integer_y = int(input())
array = []
if integer_y in range(1, 100):
    for i in range(1, 100):
        if i * i + i <= integer_y:
            array.append(i)
    print(max(array))
elif integer_y in range(100, 1000):
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        if i * i + i <= integer_y:
            array.append(i)
    print(max(array))
elif integer_y in range(1000, 10000):
    for i in range(1, 10000):
        if i * i + i <= integer_y:
            array.append(i)
    print(max(array))
```

But I need to keep doing like this, which looks bad. Is there a way to do this better and faster? The time limit is 1 second.

Comment: Why the tripple if-else?

Comment: @CutePoison I'm assuming because they know that the biggest x won't be in a certain range of numbers (the ranges in the code are incorrect but the general idea is probably that). For example, you already know that the biggest x such that `x^2 + x = 10000` will not be 10, so why test it?

Comment: Aaah.. that way. Gotcha (didnt noticed the different ranges actually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this easily with a divide and conquer algorithm, a sort of variation of the binary search.

Basically, you have a range of possible `x`, and select the one in the middle. If that `x` is valid for `x^2 + x ≤ y`, that means that the highest `x` is either that number or a bigger one. Otherwise, it must be lower. When the lowest possible `x` you have is also the current `x`, that means you have already narrowed the range down to only one number, which will be the largest one that follows the rule.

This way you can divide by 2 the amount of possible `x`s every iteration, improving dramatically the speed of the algorithm.

This is how I wrote the algorithm in python:

```
y = int(input())
low_x = 0
high_x = y

while True:
    x = (low_x + high_x)//2
    if x*x + x <= y:
        if low_x == x:
            break
        low_x = x
    else:
        high_x = x

print(low_x)
```

Keep in mind that this is python 3, in python 2 you should change the 6th line for `x = (low_x + high_x)/2`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this -

```
integer_y = int(input())
array = []

for i in range(integer_y):
    if i * i + i <= integer_y:
        array.append(i)

print(max(array))
```

Or, use a list comprehension which is faster -

```
integer_y = int(input())
array = [i for i in range(integer_y) if i*i + i <= integer_y]

print(max(array))
```